# How to show property of a UserControl in Properties panel

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I created a `UserControl` in VB.NET. I used following code to set some text to a `TextBox` via code, it works when I refer to it via code, but the issue is it doesn't show up in *Properties* window.

```vb
Dim text1_text As String = Nothing

<
    DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content),
    Category("Appearance"),
    Description("The text to be shown in textbox"),
    Browsable(True),
    EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)
>
Property Text1 As String
    Get
        Return text1_text
    End Get
    Set
        text1_text = Value
        TextBox1.Text = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Shows up for me.  Rebuild your solution maybe.

Comment: I tried :( it doesn't appear on mine, is it appears in the correct category too? :(

Comment: Yes, it appears in the "Appearance" category when I toggle the view.  You have something else going on we can't see.

Comment: If you mean you cannot see the property in the UC's Designer's Properties panel, then, no. You can see the property when the UC is in run-time mode. Meaning, inside a Form. Btw, make the Property `Public`, change `Dim text1_text as string = nothing` in `Private text1_text As String = String.Empty` and `textbox1.Text = text1_text` in the Setter (you hand-wrote this; better copy your code instead). You could derive your UC from a Base Control class that inherits `UserControl`... (long story).